# How to break an audio file into tracks when burning to CD

Tags: itunes, cd-burning

I have a lecture that fills an entire CD when I burn it using iTunes.

The problem is, it isn't broken into tracks, it is a single track and it makes jumping around difficult.

How can I break it out into say 10 minute tracks?

Answer (score 2):

You could use any free audio editor for Mac OS X, e.g., Audacity, to manually break it up into tracks.  Might be a bit more tedious than you were hoping for, though.

Comment: I was hoping for: how many minutes per track? 10 minutes click! done.

Answer (score 0):

Magic Cutter (on the App Store) can do this more automatically -- it can split by time or "by silence", scanning for pauses in the audio. I assume you want to break more than just one lecture, as you want something more convenient than the perfectly good Audacity answer.